# cleanest way to pass bean-data from jsp to js with json without ajax

Tags: javascript, java, spring, jsp, jsp-tags

What is the cleanest way to pass a bean from a spring controller to the js without using ajax?

I use a spring controller who return a jsp and beans, but I want the content of the bean to be transmit to the js used by my page.

I've read that I can transform my bean to json with the controller, then put it in a js var,

```
    mav.put("beanInJson",toJson(mybean))
...
<script> var bean=Json.stringify('${beanInJson}')</script
```

but I want to do it in only one step, without having to do the conversion in the controller

I search some jsp taglib which I can use like that:

```
mav.put("bean", mybean)
...
<script> var bean:${fn:toJson(bean)}</script>
```

Do you know any lib who allow-it? Is that the cleanest way to do it wihout using ajax?

Comment: You can bind your bean to a model and then access its properties dirctly in the jsp page as well as in the javascript like <script type="text/javascript">var myVar = "${model.paramOne}";</script>

Comment: I can't do that: I 've to much properties, and to much beans on to much jsp and to much controller. I need an automated solution.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere in the code you will need to do the conversion.If you do not want to do it in the controller, you can do it in your JSPs'.To convert an object to JSON, you can use Jackson library's ObjectMapper class.

Comment: Yes, but I thing strange than there is no tag-lib who do that directly.

Answer (score 0):

In JSP you can write:

```
<script>
    var mybean = ${beanInJson};
</script>
```

In Controller you can write:

```
    mav.put("beanInJson", new JSONObject(mybean));
```

everything you need is to add the *json* dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20160212</version>
    </dependency>
```

`mybean` in Java code can be an Object or a Map, see org.json:json javadoc.

Comment: Do you think it's the cleanest way to do it ?

Comment: of course. just one jar dependency and no js libs. and EL jars are included by most java web servers.

Comment: Also , I cannot do it for all the object that I put on mav. I need a taglib solution

Comment: any Java Bean object can be converted to JSON with `new JSONObject(...)`